# Command not found in Docker when running from Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to build and run the docker according the Dockerfile.

The code is (before I cloned my git repo etc):

```
sh 'docker build -t myimage .'
sh 'docker run myimage'
```

The Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM node:12.2.0-alpine AS build
COPY . /frontend
WORKDIR /src
CMD apt-get update
CMD gradle build
```

The docker build command seems to be success with result:

```
Successfully built 0329878899fc
Successfully tagged myimage:latest
```

but when executing the docker run command, it says:

```
    + docker run myimage
    /bin/sh: gradle: not found

ERROR: script returned exit code 127
```

I tried to remove `CMD gradle` and kept only `CMD apt-get update`, but then it says **apt-get not found.**

If I replaced `CMD` with `RUN`, then the **docker build** is not executed and says the same error.

Comment: try $ docker run -id <imagename> and then do $ docker exec -it <container-name> into container and try the commands if they work or not first

Comment: can you please explain? Should I use docker run --id myimage ? I did not find the --id in the documentation,

Comment: its hypen 
$ docker run -i -d <image-name>

Comment: alpine don;t support apt-get , you can use apk

Comment: Abhishek, Op was already running docker build. It's not helpful to recommend that they run the container in the background when we can see that the issue is they can not run their container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apt won't be available, as you're using an alpine Linux container which uses the Apk package manager.

It seems the node image does not include Gradle by default, so you will have to install it using a RUN command.

You can do that through apt by switching to a debian based image, or by searching for the Gradle package for Alpine linux

Comment: RUN apk add bash vim curl wget jq docker git tar unzip bash-completion ca-certificates gradle maven

Comment: You are right, I changed alpine to Ubuntu and now apt is working fine, but gradle is still missing. Is there an easy way to install gradle in RUN command?

Comment: keep your image size minimalistic ( like alpine and then customize )

Comment: Installing Gradle should be as easy as following the guide on their website. Those Linux commands can be used in run directives

Comment: yeah, thank you guys, I kept alpine and apk and managed to install gradle, seems working now. Thanks!